# When I merge my release branch into main, and then into dev to incorporate the changes there, my dev says it's X commits ahead, X commits behind. Why?

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I'm following the gitflow branching [model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). I follow the guidelines quite closely.

- I create a release branch from dev, and make final bugfixes and adjustments there
- I then merge this into main, and then into dev, and then delete the release branch
- I use the --no-ff (no fast-forward) flag when merging my release branch into both main and dev
- the only thing that I currently don't follow is tagging my main from git after incorporating the changes from release into it. Instead I tag it from the GitHub repo using the releases feature.

However, my dev branch now says this:

> This branch is 1 commit ahead, 1 commit behind main.

I'm confused by this. It appears that the new merge commit (caused by merging release into dev and main) on each branch is the only difference. Is this supposed to happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: (I've not heard of "feed forward" before)

Comment: Before you started all this, what was the dev branch status then? Was it up-to-date, or was it behind/ahead or both?

Comment: By "and then into dev", do you mean you merge your release branch into dev, or main into dev?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen release into dev

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen before making the release branch, dev was ahead of main by a commit. this was the change that I wanted to add to main in a new release. I made another commit in release before attempting to merge it back into dev, and also into main.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ahh sorry about that, I meant fast-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely fine, and expected in certain situations. Let's walk through what happened:

1. You created branch `release` from the tip of `develop`. At this moment `develop` and `release` are identical.
2. You add some commits with bug fixes to `release` (or not, it doesn't actually change the outcome for the purposes of this question).
3. Once you're happy with `release`, you deploy it and merge it into `main` using the `--no-ff` (no fast-forward) flag. This creates a new merge commit on `main`. So at this moment `release` and `main` have identical contents, but `main` has one extra commit on it.
4. Now you also merge `release` back down into `develop`, also using `--no-ff`. This creates a new commit on `develop` that isn't on `release` or `main`.
5. Now you delete `release`.

So at this point, `develop` has **at least** 1 commit on it that isn't on `main`, and `main` has **exactly** one commit on it that isn't in `develop`. Presumably you didn't add any commits to `develop` since creating the `release` branch, and therefore `develop` would be exactly 1 commit ahead of `main`, and exactly 1 commit behind `main`.

**Note:** the next time you do a `release` branch the same process will occur, but you will end up with 2 commits on `main` that aren't in `develop`, and this will continue incrementing until you do your first `hotfix` branch, which will bring all of those older merge commits back into `develop` all in one shot. This is expected, but can be confusing the first time you see it.

**Tip:** After experiencing the `hotfix` branch bringing many merge commits back into `develop`, now when I work in repos that use Git Flow, after merging `release` into `main`, I prefer to merge `main` into `develop` rather than `release` into `develop`. The contents will be identical, but now `develop` won't be behind `main` anymore. This also has the added advantage of making it easier to determine if any `release` branch is fully up to date with `main` before you deploy it; you simply need to make sure the commit `master` points to is also in `release`.

Comment: What did you mean by this: 

"...this will continue incrementing until you do your first `hotfix` branch, which will bring all of those older merge commits back into `develop` all in one shot. This is expected but can be confusing the first time you see it."

How do you use a `hotfix` branch to merge all the commits into `develop`? I thought the hotfix branch in GitFlow was for resolving bugs and used to merge into `master` and `develop` separately. This is something I'm working through right now. My dev branch keeps getting the 1 commit ahead and behind `master`  with no changes.

Comment: @thelovesmith When I started using Git Flow, I had 10 releases before I needed a hotfix. At this point `main` was 10 (empty) merge commits ahead of `develop`. When you create a `hotfix`, you start from `main`, which means those extra 10 (empty) merge commits are in the `hotfix`. When you complete the `hotfix` and merge it into `develop`, it brings the hotfix changes along with those 10 empty merge commits. After witnessing that for the first time, I decided to start merging into `main` and then merging `main` into `develop` instead (as described in the Tip to my answer).

Comment: Note that what you're witnessing is completely fine, and you can leave it alone if you wish. If you start using my Tip, then after merging `master` down to `develop`, `develop` will be (at least) 1 commit ahead and 0 behind. That 0 behind is the part I prefer and the advantage of using my Tip. In my case, `develop` is always hundreds of commits ahead of `master` but should almost always be 0 commits behind `master`. Note the difference with my Tip is in commit graph only; the state is the same either way you choose.